# Can be this batch file improved to include sub-folders?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have these lines in a .bat file:

```
@echo off
pushd %*
for %%j in (*) do type nul > "%%j"
popd
```

If I run it it changes all the file's sizes to 0, including the batch file. If I use it in CMD I can specify the folders name to change as: `makeitzero.bat FOLDER_NAME`

But I know just a little about programming, so I wonder if I could include sub-folders too (if I run it OR from command-line)?

Thanks!

Note: I'm a new user on this site, and I'm not quite sure how to use it properly, so if I made a mistake (wrong title, bad tags, irrelevant info, etc.) I'd be glad to hear it, and to do it better next time.

**Edit 1**: `for /r` did the trick. This works like a charm:

```
@echo off
for /r "D:\DeleteInThis" %%a in (.) do (
    pushd %%a
    pushd %*
    for %%j in (*) do type nul > "%%j"
    popd
    )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOR` has several [mode switches](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to make the command to work in various ways. You should check out `FOR /F` which allows you to loop through the output of a command. Use `DIR` [command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to list files and directories in all  subdirectories. Use the `/S` switch to include all subdirectories and `/B` to have a plain output (just the full pathname of files and folders).

```
dir /s /b ".\*"
```

To combine the output of `DIR` with the loop modify your FOR command to something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('dir /s /b ".\*"') do type nul > "%%j"
```

**WARNING**: Read everything before running any of the command above! The topic is about changing the size of multiple files to 0 which means DELETING THE CONTENT OF FILES!

Comment: damn.. noob here just tried to run that last line trying to list all *.exe in sub folders and deleted it all .. no fair warning :/